# laravel pivot update column ambigious

Tags: php, laravel, pivot

Hi have a problem with an update function it says the column updated_at is ambigious and it is. how can I make the updated_at to product.updated_at. my error.

my call to update:
$product->attributes()->wherePivot('id', $attribute['id'])->update($input);

my error:
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'updated_at' in field list is ambiguous (SQL: update `attributes` inner join `attribute_product` on `attributes`.`id` = `attribute_product`.`attribute_id` set `sku` = TEST, `model` = , `attribute_product`.`name` = Color, `unitprice` = 10.00, `sellprice` = 20.00, `discount` = 0, `active` = 0, `ordering` = 1, `updated_at` = 2015-03-25 02:44:01 where `attribute_product`.`product_id` = 1 and `attribute_product`.`id` = 1)

Answer (score 0):

just add the following line to your product model

`const UPDATED_AT = "product.updated_at";`

& attribute_product model

`const UPDATED_AT = "attribute_product.updated_at";`

update your model updated_at to include table name.